# MVC strongly typed view cannot find my model in the namespace within the same project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, namespaces, strongly-typed-view

I'm getting the following error when trying to open an ASP.NET MVC3 website using a strongly typed view.

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Survey' does not exist in the namespace 'MyWeb.Models' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
public class _Page_Views_Home_Survey_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<MyWeb.Models.Survey> {
```

Note:

- I only have one project in the solution.
- MyWeb.Models.Survey exists and is public.
- Inside my Survey.cshtml file, I have full access to intellisense.
- Pages that are not strongly typed work find.
- In my web config, I have the following:

```
    <pages>
    <namespaces>
    ...
    <add namespace="MyWeb.Models"/>
    </namespaces>
    </pages>
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: What version of the MVC DLL are you referencing?  Is there a chance you're referencing MVC2 instead of MVC3?  Also, it might be prudent to double-check the framework target.

Comment: @Ross - MVC is version 3.0.0.0. Target framework is .NET 4.0.

Comment: edited to fix config html encoding

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating a new project and copying all files into the new project. There was probably something in a web.config somewhere or some other cruft that just got left behind along the way. I'll leave this open in case other people have an easier solution, but if other people run into the same problem, this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by deleting the .edmx file (including deleting the connection string too) and then readding them again.